# How to convert class component to function component with hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

my code class component

```
raf = (callback) => {
     var self = this;
        if (this.requestFrame) raf.cancel(this.requestFrame);
        this.requestFrame = raf(function () {
            self.requestFrame = undefined;
            callback();
        });
    }

update = (callback) => {
    this.raf(function () { this._update(callback) });
}
```

my code function component

```
const raf = (callback) => {
        if (Scrollbars.requestFrame) raf.cancel(Scrollbars.requestFrame);
        Scrollbars.requestFrame = raf(() => {
            Scrollbars.requestFrame = undefined;
            callback();
        });
    };

    const update = (callback) => {
        raf(() => _update(callback));
    };
```

I am switching from class component to function component but when i switch I get error "Maximum call stack size exceeded" in function **raf**.
Someone please help me.

Comment: Can you update your question to include a more comprehensive component code example, both the class component and the function component you are working on, so we can see more of what your code is doing? Typically when this error occurs it's because the component is unconditionally updating state and render looping.

Comment: here is my error code "https://imgur.com/rGYtx9X"   tried with class component but no problem, but with function component it gives error like this "https://imgur.com/DAMyhpt". here is my component "https://imgur.com/yKAh4wt"

Answer (score 0):

In your function component add below code and try:

```
const update = (callback) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    raf(() => _update(callback));
  }, []);
};
```

Comment: This breaks the [Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html), you cannot call React hooks from nested functions.